# How do I run a docker container based on its name from `docker ps -a`?

Tags: docker

By default docker leaves a bunch of dead volumes around.

`$ docker ps -a`

`61e99f563834 jolly_swanson       user/name:version    "command"   52 seconds ago      Exited (130) 51 seconds ago`

Why doesn't `docker run jolly_swanson` restart that container with its old data? I feel like I must be missing something from the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confusing images and containers. Docker leaves dead *containers* around, not images (and not volumes either).

`docker run` creates a new container from an existing image. So `docker run jolly_swanson` does not work because `jolly_swanson` is the name of a container, not an image.

To start an existing container, use `start`, e.g. `docker start jolly_swanson`.